# how to validate regex for open API using spectral rule

Tags: regex, spectral

I am creating a custom rule for spectral for mapping the path and path parameters but having some difficulty with regex. I have the following rules:

```
1) URI MUST be in lowercase OR with combined words using the hyphen( - ). Aka kebab-case
Example:
https://api.com/payments/pending
https://api.com/payments/pending-payments

2) Path and Query string parameters MUST be in lowerCamelCase.
Example:
   https://api.com/payments/payments/{paymentId}
   https://api.com/payments/pending-payments/?paymentType=xxx
```

In the spectral rule set I have defined my custom rule like this:

```
paths-kebab-case:
description: Paths should be kebab-case.
message: "{{property}} should be kebab-case (lower-case and separated with hyphens)"
severity: error
given: $.paths[*]~
then:
  function: pattern
  functionOptions:
    match: "^(\/([\da-z]+(-[\da-z]+)? |\{[a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]+)*}) )+$"


path-parameter-must-lower-camel-case:
message: Path parameters must be lowerCamelCase
description: MUST use lowerCamelCase
severity: error
given: $.paths.*~
then:
  function: pattern
  functionOptions:
    match: '^[a-z][a-z]*(([A-Z][a-z]+)*[A-Z]?|([a-z]+[A-Z])*|[A-Z])$'
```

It seems to be not validating properly. like if my path contains only a single path, I am getting the error.

```
 10:9    error  path-parameter-must-lower-camel-case  Path parameters must be lowerCamelCase
  25:9  warning  parser                                Mapping key must be a string scalar rather than number
  48:9  warning  parser                                Mapping key must be a string scalar rather than number
 56:17    error  path-parameter-must-lower-camel-case  Path parameters must be lowerCamelCase
  70:9  warning  parser                                Mapping key must be a string scalar rather than number
```

Here is the swagger API:

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger Petstore
  license:
    name: MIT
servers:
  - url: http://petstore.swagger.io/v1
paths:
  /pets:
    get:
      summary: List all pets
      operationId: listPets
      tags:
        - pets
      parameters:
        - name: limit
          in: query
          description: How many items to return at one time (max 100)
          required: false
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int32
      responses:
        200:
          description: An paged array of pets
          headers:
            x-next:
              description: A link to the next page of responses
              schema:
                type: string
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pets"
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"
    post:
      summary: Create a pet
      operationId: createPets
      tags:
        - pets
      responses:
        201:
          description: Null response
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"
  /pets/{petId}:
    get:
      summary: Info for a specific pet
      operationId: showPetById
      tags:
        - pets
      parameters:
        - name: petId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The id of the pet to retrieve
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: Expected response to a valid request
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pets"
        default:
          description: unexpected error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"
components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      required:
        - id
        - name
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        name:
          type: string
        tag:
          type: string
    Pets:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
    Error:
      required:
        - code
        - message
      properties:
        code:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        message:
          type: string
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the pattern on your lower-kebab-case rule may not work.

This is the one I use:

```
then:
  function: pattern
  functionOptions:
    match: "^(\/|[a-z0-9-]+|{[a-zA-Z0-9_|-]+})+$"
```